# Model Setup with second normal form for ManyToManyFields

Tags: django

I'm new to databases and new to Django. I need your help.

I want to have for example a database with Persons having e.g. different shirts. Shirts have different lengths.

For example Peter has three shirts. A red T-shirt, a blue longsleeve shirt and a blue t-shirt.

Marcus has also has a red shirt, but it should only have long sleeves.

How do I create a model, where the second normalized Foreign- or ManyToManyField can have different values, depending on the top level (Person) data?

Or do I need to have each shirt as a different entry (blue long, blue short etc.) and relate this to the person?

Django usually creates an additional table with an ID the ID of the Person and the ID of the shirt.
Is there a way to add a third row for the sleeves then?

My Django Model is something like this:

```
Class Length(models.Model):
    name_length = models.CharField(max_length=10) # e.g. short, long, half

Class Shirt(models.Model):
    name_shirt = models.CharField(max_length=20) # e.g. red-one, blue-one
    shirt_length = models.ManyToManyField(Length)

Class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    persons_shirt = models.ManyToManyField(Shirt)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be:

```
class Length(models.Model):
    name_length = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Shirt(models.Model):
    name_shirt = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    shirt_length = models.ForeignKey(Length)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    persons_shirt = models.ManyToManyField(Shirt)
```

So here we are, Shirst is separate instanse and only depends on the Length, if the `name_shirts` related to the color, maybe it's better to `ForeignKey(Color)`, but if it's closely to unique name, then your version is alright.
The answer would be you need to have each shirt as single entry. And it would be more correct to say that each shirt TYPE should be a single entry. Because if there is no difference between Peter's and Marcus's red T-shirt, then the red T-shirt is a single entry, not depending on person's belongings.

BTW `class` starts with lowercase letter.